# Powershell - Check if Text Box Contents Have Changed

Tags: winforms, events, powershell, textbox

Is there anyway I can check if the contents of a text box has changed?

Say, for example, I made a text box:

```
$InputBox1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox 
$InputBox1.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(20,50) 
$InputBox1.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(150,20) 
$objForm.Controls.Add($InputBox1)
```

Then I set an output to the textbox:

```
 $InputBox1.text= "Hello"
```

I want to know if there is an event handler that can detect if the contents of the text box have been changed (after initial loading in the GUI - that is, when InputBox1.text becomes != Hello)

It has to detect it real-time - meaning that anytime the user clicks the textbox and alters the content - an event is raised which can be used as a condition to modify other parts of the code.

Basic breakdown on what I need to do:

1. Gets a value from Active Directory (i.e. accountname)
2. UI is loaded. Account Name is loaded into the textbox.
3. If user modifies contents of a textbox, enable a button to allow saving the new value.

I have a working code which stores the current value and puts the entire function into a "wait for text change" loop but am looking for a more elegant way to get it done.

Comment: There is the [`TextChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.textchanged(v=vs.110).aspx) event, doesn't it work as desired?

Comment: Thank you. Knew I was missing something fundamental - events. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Very late to the party here, but you can easily achieve this with the **Add_TextChanged()** method on the TextBox object.

```
$InputBox1.Add_TextChanged({Write-Host "Text changed, do something"})
```